# laravel on master account for alle employees

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authorization

I have one challenge regarding a laravel 4.5 project web application.

My application is a incident registration form for all employees for many companys.

Every employees of the concerning company can only create incident en saved it. 
Every company has single “admin” account login, who can edit,delete and see list off all the incidents of concerning company.

What i'm looking for is a main user account,for numerous employees -  and single “admin” account login for concerning company.

I use 1 Mysql database and 1 table for incident registration for alle the companys.

Example Companys :

- Company       | main user account          |  admin  account
- coca cola     |coca_cola_employees         |  coca_cola_admin
- philips       |philips_employees           |  philips_admin

Hopefully somebody  know a solution.

Comment: what have you tried so far? Please post code snippets and what errors are you facing if any?

Answer (score 0):

how about creating companies table with company details and then adding foreign key to user table to identify the users company and adding a flag in users table to find out role of user i.e. a boolean is_admin which defaults to false and will only be true for the admin

relations are:

one company has many users 
or
a user belongs to a company

a user will have a specific role i.e. either admin or ordinary user...